# ACE Editor deletes Control Character

Tags: javascript, string, ace-editor

given the Situation there is an ACE-Editor which is created with a string containing control characters like \x00 or \0. After some editing I send the new String back to the server using `editor.getValue()`. The problem is that ACE deletes the control character. Even if don't change anything the result is the same.

**Question:** Does anybody know where/when ACE deletes those control characters and how to disable it?

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Only change to the text that ace does automatically is normalizing line ending (`\r`, `\n`). It doesn't change "\x00" which can be checked by doing:

```
editor.setValue("\0"); 
editor.getValue() == "\0"
```

deletion of control characters most likely happens during the upload, maybe on the server.